# Not calculating correct number or refreshing

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets and have just noticed a very worrying issue.

I have a situation where I have a number (for example 4.99) in the left column and the right column through a series of formulae may come out as 30% or so. I changed the number in the left to 5 and the number is the right column jumped to 50% or so (highly unexpected to see such a large jump for such a small increase, so I decided to investigate). When I typed 4.99 back into the left box, the result in the right was just slightly lower than the 50% or so.

I then checked several other numbers in the left column. It turns out that this was the same for all of them. I.e. the number in the right column was not calculating properly until I changed the number in the left column and pressed enter. How is this possible? I have never had this problem with Excel and I don't know what to do other than to migrate back to Excel as I am now doubting the reliability of all the spreadsheets I have on Google Sheets.

Has anybody else come across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out moments after posting this.

In the column for some reason some of the cells were considered numbers and some text. I performed an if statement (<10), which came out FALSE for all cells considered text.

Quite dangerous - surely the cell on the right should show an error and not assume FALSE?